# Fastest way to unpack bits into single precision floats

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, optimization, 64-bit

This is platform specific question. Speed is crucial.
What is the fastest way to unpack a byte into an array of 8 single precision floats so that zeroes map into zeroes and ones map into ones?

I ended up using 8 bit masks and 7 bit shifts to unpack into 8 int32's and then an AVX instruction to convert int32's into floats.

My platform is Windows 64 bit running on AVX (but no AVX2) capable CPU. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for 32-bit or 64-bit floating point numbers?

Comment: 32 bit floating point numbers

Comment: why not prepare a `1.0f` in CPU reg 1 and a `0.0f` in CPU reg 2 so you can use a single `MOV` instruction for 'creating' the new float?

Comment: `1` in 32-bit float is `0x3F800000`. `0` is `0x0`. Other than what you tried, I would try looping over the each bit with the mask/shift and if the bit is '1' writing `0x3F800000` in the corresponding slot, otherwise keeping the array  zeroed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops, conditions and going through an actual array in memory are of course not the vector way. So here's an other idea, though it's a bit annoying in only AVX. Since without AVX2 you can do almost nothing with an ymm register (nothing useful anyway), just use two xmm registers and then in the end `vinsertf128` the high part to form the whole thing. Mixing like this is OK as long as the operations on xmm registers use VEX encoded instructions (so 'v' goes in front of everything, even when it may seem unnecessary).

Anyway, the idea is to put a copy of the byte in every dword, AND with the right bit per lane and compare to form masks. In the end we can do a single bitwise AND to turn the masks into 0f or 1f.

So, first get that byte everywhere, let's say it's in `eax`, doesn't really matter:

```
vmovd xmm0, eax
vpshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

Extract the right bits:

```
vpand xmm0, xmm0, [low_mask]
vpand xmm1, xmm0, [high_mask]
```

The masks are `1, 2, 4, 8` and `16, 32, 64, 128` (this is in memory order, if you use `_mm_set_epi32` they have to be the other way around)

Compare to form the masks:

```
vpxor xmm2, xmm2, xmm2
vpcmpgtd xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
vpcmpgtd xmm1, xmm1, xmm2
```

Merge:

```
vinsertf128 ymm0, ymm0, xmm1, 1
```

Turn into 0f or 1f:

```
vandps ymm0, ymm0, [ones]
```

`ones` is just 1f duplicated 8 times.

I don't know if this is faster, but it's worth a try. Also, none of this was tested.

I tried to convert it to intrinsics, but I have no idea what I'm doing (and it's not tested). Also, be careful that it compiles with VEX prefixes, or it'll cause expensive mode-switching.

```
// broadcast
__m128i low = _mm_set1_epi32(mask);
__m128i high = _mm_set1_epi32(mask);
// extract bits
low = _mm_and_si128(low, _mm_set_epi32(8, 4, 2, 1));
high = _mm_and_si128(high, _mm_set_epi32(128, 64, 32, 16));
// form masks
low = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(low, _mm_setzero_si128());
high = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(high, _mm_setzero_si128());
// stupid no-op casts
__m256 low2 = _mm256_castps128_ps256(_mm_castsi128_ps(low));
__m128 high2 = _mm_castsi128_ps(high);
// merge
__m256 total = _mm256_insertf128_ps(low2, high2, 1);
// convert to 0f or 1f
total = _mm256_and_ps(total, _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f));
```

With GCC at least, that generates OK code. It uses `vbroadcastss` for the `set1` (instead of the `vpshufd`'s that I used), I'm not sure how good that idea is (it means it has to bounce that int through memory).

With AVX2 it can be much simpler:

```
__m256i x = _mm256_set1_epi32(mask); 
x = _mm256_and_si256(x, _mm256_set_epi32(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1));
x = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(x, _mm256_setzero_si256());
x = _mm256_and_si256(x, _mm256_set1_epi32(0x3F800000));
return _mm256_castsi256_ps(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't preprocessing be faster? 2^8 possibilities is pretty much, but then again, just split it into two parts, and it's only 2^4 = 16 variables.

Make array consiting of 16 "values", where each value is array filled with 4 floats with right values. Then your cost would be only 2 * (copy data from preprocessed array to new array).

I'm not too deep into assembly, but two copy's should be faster then some loops etc.

```
unsigned char myByte; // input byte (pattern to create floats)
float preprocessingArrays[16][4] = {
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, // 0000
    // ...
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }  // 1111
};

float result[8];
std::memcpy(&result[0], &preprocessingArrays[myByte >> 4][0], 16);
std::memcpy(&result[4], &preprocessingArrays[myByte & 15][0], 16);
// 16 = platform-specific -> floats should be 32bits -> 4bytes * 4 floats = 16
```

This is written from hand, but as you can see mine loop would consists of two memcpys, one bitshift and one binary AND operation (or only one, but bigger, memcpy, if you want to make preprocessing for 2^8 values).

For C(++) only code i think this would beat loops etc. but assembler code might be faster, i'm not that sure. **Maybe you could perform `memcpy` operation using assembler and in one go read whole 4 floats and then write it in another one call.** AVX seems to support up to 16 256bits registers, so it might be possible to just calculate from which register (of 16 possible values) copy value where and this would be very fast.

Also not to write so much code yourself, just make simple program which would print preprocessing values for you, copy it and paste into original program :)

Comment: Looks good, be careful with that char though, it could be signed and then `myByte >> 4` could cause trouble

Comment: Thanks, i keep forgeting that even though it's bit operation, it does work diffrent for negative numbers. :)

Comment: You can't read from a variable register by the way, at least not easily if there are more than 2 choices

Comment: @harold: You may not be able to index into the SSE register table, but indexing into level 1 cache is very fast.  Just make sure that `preprocessingArrays` is overaligned.

Comment: Welp, thats a shame, but still, as @BenVoigt says, it should be pretty fast copy (from what i read, even std::memcpy is optimised to use sse 128-bit registers for copy, which would lead to belive that as long as `preprocessingArrays` are fast to retrieve, then it would be very fast operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
void byteToFloat(const uint8_t               byteIn, 
                       float *const restrict floatOut)
{
     floatOut[0]=(byteIn&0x01)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[1]=(byteIn&0x02)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[2]=(byteIn&0x04)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[3]=(byteIn&0x08)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[4]=(byteIn&0x10)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[5]=(byteIn&0x20)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[6]=(byteIn&0x40)?1.0f:0.0f;
     floatOut[7]=(byteIn&0x80)?1.0f:0.0f;
}
```

> In x86-64 architectures from both Intel and AMD, branch predication
>   may be performed through the use of conditional move operations
>   (cmove): a source operand is conditionally moved to the destination
>   operand depending on the value of a flag register.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication

Answer (score -2):

Indexing, as @RippeR suggests, is my first guess too.

My second guess is something like this:

```
switch(theChar){
 break; case   0: result[0] = 0; ... result[7] = 0;
 break; case   1: result[0] = 0; ... result[7] = 1;
 ...
 break; case 255: result[0] = 1; ... result[7] = 1;
}
```

It's wordy code, but you could get the preprocessor to help you write it.

The reason this might be faster is the switch should turn into a jump table, and the moves should optimize pretty well.

ADDED: if you're wondering how the preprocessor could help, here's something:

```
#define FOO(x,i) result[i] = !!((x) & (1<<(i)))
#define BAR(x) break; case x: FOO(x,0);FOO(x,1); ... FOO(x,7)
switch(theChar){
 BAR(0);
 BAR(1);
 ...
 BAR(255);
}
```

Comment: I think this would be slower. Lets assume that decision which case it is is as fast in both cases, in my case i perform 2 memcpy which are optimised with SSE 128bit registers and in your case you perform 8 copies of single floats. I'd say that copy from memory which might be kept in cache if you use it for longer time is faster then assigning 8 values. Though profiling would be nice to see which is faster. Some under-the-hood optimisations might kick in.

Comment: @RippeR: You could be right. I figure I'm getting downvotes because of the macros. Somehow, those became evil at some point in time.